# Selecting item from dropdownlist dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I want to select an item dynamically from a database into a dropdownlist.
I can set value property of the dropdownlist but I am not able to set the item property, why so?
My database has text stored in it so I have to select the item from dropdownlist.

adding code of comment

```
  string strGetBooking = travService.SEL_TourManualBooking("", long.Parse(hdtmbid.Value));
  if (strGetBooking != "") 
  {
      DataSet ds = new DataSet(); 
      ds.ReadXml(new StringReader(strGetBooking)); 
      DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
      drpTour.SelectedItem = dt.Rows[0]["FKTBID"].ToString(); 
  }
```

Comment: Put some code you have tried out.

Comment: you want to select item Dynamically. And the DropDown is loaded with the value from DB. is that right ?

Comment: string strGetBooking = travService.SEL_TourManualBooking("",     long.Parse(hdtmbid.Value));

if (strGetBooking != "")
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ds.ReadXml(new StringReader(strGetBooking));
    DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];drpTour.SelectedItem = dt.Rows[0]["FKTBID"].ToString(); }

Comment: @Peru - yeas you are right , as DB stores text value i want to assign text stored in DB to selecteditem of dropdown but i am surprised i am bot able to do it !!!

Comment: you are still using `SelectedItem`, try using `SelectedText` as per my answer below..

Answer (score 3):

```
SelectedIndex -- > The index number of the selected item 
SelectedItem -->  The text of the selected item (Text And Value)
SelectedValue--> The value of the selected item 
Text-- > The value of the selected item
```

Comment: -1 for `SelectedItem -->  The text of the selected item` as item is a combination of text and value. So it should be `SelectedItem.Text`

Comment: You have to refer MSDN  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist_properties.aspx

Comment: @krshekhar Selected item implicitly refers to Text and value !

Comment: I agree to you point. Kindly edit you post so that I can change my down-voting.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
    // dropDown = Your Dropdown
    //dbValue = your database value(String Value)
    dropDown.SelectedText = dbValue;
```

**[EDIT]**

You can do this in one other way -

```
dropDown.SelectedIndex = dropDown.Items.IndexOf(dropDown.Items.FindByText(dbValue));
```

Comment: i tried this but isn't working and error says selected item can't be assigned to - it's read only..

Comment: Read. Its `SelectedText`. Not `SelectedItem`.

Comment: `item` is a combination of `value` and `text` and `selected index` is the index of the item which is selected. selected value is value which is currently selected. There is no property like `selectedText`.

Comment: You can set `drpTour.SelectedValue = dt.Rows[0]["FKTBID"].ToString()` directly.